# laptop disconnects from power then reconnects on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, laptop, hardware, indicator

I am experiencing a new problem after finally getting Ubuntu 18.04 to install on my laptop (could NOT get another OS besides Windows on it), but that is for another question.

The problem is, at random times my laptop will act like it disconnects from the power adapter and the reconnects. I hear the notable "tick-tick when something is disconnected from Ubuntu, then I see that the power icon at the top of the screen doesn't show the lightning bolt any more. Then a few moments later, I hear the sound of something reconnecting, and then the lightning bolt is back in its place.

I do NOT under any circumstance want to promote Windows here, but I do want to point out (because it may be helpful) that this issue wasn't present in Window's 10 (go figure). 
  I also want to point out that my hardware is VERY weird. here is the output of `lshw`: [lshw-paste-via-privatebin](https://privatebin.net/?a3db39e637382950#3viDhViRzjJbiRnsmFrAWbLDvDUErDxdcVARQ6WKmQZk)

here is also a screenshot of all of the errors that show up in my logs:[screenshot](https://pasteboard.co/IBfmS34.png)

I am only posting the error logs just in case someone notices that something in there is related to the issue that I am having. If I can provide more information, please tell me and I will edit my question ASAP!
I would also like to note (just in case) that I was NOT able to get ANY other flavor of Ubuntu installed besides the vanilla version. The installer would keep crashing at about 30% creating partitions, but that is for another topic itself. I also have NOT done anything special to this system, just installed the OS and added my usual programs,that you can see on the side of the screenshot.

EDIT: I also just noticed these weird lines in `dmesg`

`[10010.674277] acpi LNXPOWER:16: Turning OFF
[10010.674344] acpi LNXPOWER:15: Turning OFF
[10010.674409] acpi LNXPOWER:14: Turning OFF
[10010.674473] acpi LNXPOWER:13: Turning OFF
[10010.674538] acpi LNXPOWER:12: Turning OFF
[10010.674603] acpi LNXPOWER:11: Turning OFF
[10010.674666] acpi LNXPOWER:10: Turning OFF
[10010.674730] acpi LNXPOWER:0f: Turning OFF
[10010.674794] acpi LNXPOWER:0e: Turning OFF
[10010.674857] acpi LNXPOWER:0d: Turning OFF
[10010.674920] acpi LNXPOWER:0c: Turning OFF
[10010.674984] acpi LNXPOWER:0b: Turning OFF
[10010.675047] acpi LNXPOWER:0a: Turning OFF
[10010.675110] acpi LNXPOWER:09: Turning OFF
[10010.675172] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
[10010.675236] acpi LNXPOWER:07: Turning OFF
[10010.675298] acpi LNXPOWER:06: Turning OFF
[10010.675362] acpi LNXPOWER:05: Turning OFF
[10010.675425] acpi LNXPOWER:04: Turning OFF
[10010.675488] acpi LNXPOWER:03: Turning OFF`

Are they related to whats going on?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I get a popup from the software updater fairly frequently, that tells me that there is a problem, and asks me if I want to report it. Of course I report it every time.

Answer (score 0):

SHORT ANSWER:

the charger was not capable of supplying enough power to keep up with the needs of this laptop.

LONG ANSWER:

So after a while of trying different things, i finally figured it out. I had noticed that the charger i happened to be using on this power hungry laptop was getting VERY hot, so i decided to hack together another one, of a much higher rating.
  it worked.